# Why do match and scan return different results for the same regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

I tried several options for matching in Ruby, and was confused by the results because `match` and `scan` return different results. This is an example:

```
s ="C:\Users\rdo\AppData\Local\Temp/ccqZSpeQ.o: In function `main':\r\nmain.c:(.text+0x8): undefined reference to `some_function'"

%r[([\w\.\/]+):(.+)].match(s)
# => #<MatchData "C:Users\rdoAppDataLocalTemp/ccqZSpeQ.o: In function `main':\r" 1:"C" 2:"Users\rdoAppDataLocalTemp/ccqZSpeQ.o: In function `main':\r">

s.scan(/([\w\.\/]+):(.+)/)
# => [["C", "Users\rdoAppDataLocalTemp/ccqZSpeQ.o: In function `main':\r"], ["main.c", "(.text+0x8): undefined reference to `some_function'"]]
```

I expected that `match` would return a result like `scan` but it did not. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: What’s the confusion here? They are different methods that do different things and return different things. The documentation is fairly clear about what each does.

Comment: Actually I don not understand why `match` matched only one part or expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`match` and `scan` are entirely different methods, which do entirely different things and return entirely different results.

`match` tells you about the results of applying a regular expression to a string, what things were matched, their starts and lengths and which section of the pattern matched.

`scan` applies a regular expression to a string and returns an array of strings all the captured results.

Comment: does `match` an analog of `preg_match` in php?